# Show that the set of vectors $x\alpha + y\beta$ is a subspace of $V$

Tags: vector-spaces

> Given that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any two vectors in $V$, show that the set of all vectors $x\alpha + y\beta$, where $x$ and $y$ are any two real numbers, is a subspace of $V$.

Clearly $\{x\alpha + y\beta\}$ is not empty....I am not sure where to go from here. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: show that if you add two vectors of that form, or multiply one by a scalar, you get one of that form

Comment: assuming $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two elements of {$x\alpha+y\beta$}:

$x_1\alpha+y_1\beta + x_2\alpha+y_2\beta=(x_1+x_2)\alpha+(y_1+y_2)\beta$

Multiply an element by a scalar:

$c(x_1\alpha+y_1\beta)=(cx_1)\alpha+(cy_1)\beta$

Comment: take $c=0$ to get the zero vector

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Remember, $W=\{x\alpha+y\beta:\alpha,\beta\in V \text{ and } x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a subspace of $V$ if $W\subset V$ and the conditions:

1. If $v,w\in W\implies v+w\in W$.
2. If $v\in W $ and $c\in\mathbb{R}\implies cv\in W$.
3. The zero of element of $V$ is the zero element of $W$.

are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\textsf{W}=\{x\alpha+y\beta:\, x,y\in \mathbb R\}$.

- The set is non-empty since $\alpha=1\alpha+0\beta$ and $\beta=0\alpha+1\beta$ are both in $\textsf W$.
- If $x_1\alpha +y_1\beta$ and $x_2\alpha +y_2\beta$ are two arbitrary vectors in $\textsf W$, then the vector
  $$(x_1\alpha +y_1\beta)+(x_2\alpha +y_2\beta)=(x_1+x_2)\alpha +(y_1+y_2)\beta$$
  is also in $\textsf W$.
- If $x\alpha+y\beta$ is in $\textsf W$ and $\lambda$ is an arbitrary real number, then the vector $\lambda(x\alpha+y\beta)=(\lambda x)\alpha+(\lambda y)\beta$ ...